# How to install apps in Microsoft store using SYSTEM account?

Tags: permission-denied

My requirement is to install apps in Microsoft store using SYSTEM account. But they are all getting installed only using admin user privileges. When I tried to install an app in Microsoft store using `Add-AppxPackage` utility with SYSTEM user, I'm getting the following error.

> **PS C:\Windows\system32> Add-AppxPackage -Path C:\Path to file.appxbundle -Verbose VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Deploy
> package" on target "C:\Path to file.appxbundle". Add-AppxPackage :
> Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF9, Install failed. Please
> contact your software vendor. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CF9)
> Deployment Add operation rejected on package
> Microsoft.RemoteDesktop_2020.1208.2040.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe from:
> Microsoft.RemoteDesktop_2020.1208.2040.0_neutral___8wekyb3d8bbwe.appxbundle
> install request because the Local System account is not allowed to
> perform this operation. NOTE: For additional information, look for
> [ActivityId] bc984532-ed5b-0000-41db-98bc5bedd601 in the Event Log or
> use the command line Get-AppPackageLog -ActivityID
> bc984532-ed5b-0000-41db-98bc5bedd601 At line:1 char:1

- Add-AppxPackage -Path C:\Path to file ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Path to file...bbwe.appxbundle:String) [Add-AppxPackage], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand
  ```

VERBOSE: Operation completed for:
C:\Path to file.appxbundle**

Is there any way, I can install these application using SYSTEM account?

Comment: This is the same issue that I see when I am attempting to run unit tests in my CI pipeline using bamboo.  Bamboo run a service as LocalSystem, and does not have the permissions to install dependent APPX packages (specifically Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.2), and so my unit tests fail.

Comment: Hi! Did you happen to find any solution other than using the local user?